# Matrices help/double checking (with working).

Tags: matrices

[image]

Is my working correct? Do I need to change anything?

a)

r2-r1: 0 -1 0 | 0

2r1+r3 : 0 1 0 | k+2

r2+r3 : 0 0 0 | k+2 so echelon form is

1 0 1 | 1

0 -1 0 | 0

0 0 0 |k+2

b) any value of k ╪ -2, say k=1

c)

k=-2.

The equations reduce to y=0 and x+z=1 which are geometrically

two planes which intersect in a line, so there is a line of solutions.

Comment: a) is almost correct. RREF requires that the first value in every row has to be a $1$. (see: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C-2%7D%7D+rref).

b) and c) seem pretty good.

Comment: you can actually show what the solution is too, if $k=-2$...we know $y=0$, but then set $z$ equal to the parameter $t$ and substitute in for the first expression and you get $x=-t$.  Therefore your infinitely many solutions take the form $t(-1,0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd polish it up a bit, but otherwise it looks pretty good.

The matrix is
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 1 & -2 & k \\
\end{array}\right]$$
and you've reduced it to row echelon form via:
\begin{align*}
& \rightarrow_{R_2 \gets R_2-R_1}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & -2 & k
\end{array}\right] \\
& \rightarrow_{R_3 \gets R_3+2R_1}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & k+2
\end{array}\right] \\
& \rightarrow_{R_3 \gets R_3+R_2}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & k+2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
This is indeed in row echelon form.

For the latter parts, I'd say something along the lines:

- If e.g. $k=1$, then the third equation implies $0=3$, which is inconsistent.  In this case, there are no solutions.
- If $k=-2$, then the corresponding system of equations to the row echelon form is
  \begin{align*}
  x+z &=1 \\
  -y &=0 \\
  0 &=0.
  \end{align*}
  We have a free variable, so we set $z=t$ for some real number $t$.  By back substitution, we find that $y=0$ and $x=-t+1$, and so there is an infinite number of solutions given by $(x,y,z)=(-t+1,0,t)$.